# Authentication Settings for Amazon and Evernote

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

If you refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-2.2 you can see you can configure OpenID Connect (OIDC) authentication for various providers as below:

**Facebook**

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddFacebook(options =>
        {
            options.AppId = Configuration["auth:facebook:appid"];
            options.AppSecret = Configuration["auth:facebook:appsecret"];
        });
```

**Google**

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["auth:google:clientid"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["auth:google:clientsecret"];
        });
```

**Microsoft**

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["auth:microsoft:clientid"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["auth:microsoft:clientsecret"];
        });
```

My question is does anybody have the settings I would need to provide to Support Amazon and Evernote OIDC?

Comment: All `Configuration["auth:facebook:appid"];` is doing is telling the app to look in your `appsettings.json` or other config files for that path, and then return the value. So you still need to get a clientId and secret from each service, and to do that you have to go to their websites and learn about their APIs. For example, I often use the Google . I would assume Amazon and Evernote are the same. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Thank you for commenting, completely understand the the client id and secrets are being read from configuration.  My question was more around does anybody know what the settings are for Evernote and Amazon.  As you may of guessed...there is not a .AddAmazon or .AddEvernote extension method, there I am assuming that I would need to use the generic AddOpenIdConnect method and provide it with the correct configuration.  Does anybody know what these settings are?

Answer (score 4):

You can find Login with Amazon reference [here](https://login.amazon.com/website)
Amazon still does not support OIDC, but supports OAuth. However the default `OAuthHandler` for dotnet does not provide `UserInfoEndpoint` handling. That's why you have to either implement the call to `UserInfoEndpoint` (can grab it from oidc) or hack the OIDC to make it thinking that it has id_token whenever it has not. I've passed the second route. Little bit dirty trick, but I've got my user identified.

```cs
.AddOpenIdConnect("lwa", "LoginWithAmazon", options =>
{
  options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
  options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

  options.Authority = "https://www.amazon.com/";
  options.ClientId = "amzn1.application-oa2-client.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  options.ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  options.ResponseType = "code";
  options.ResponseMode = "query";
  options.SaveTokens = true;
  options.CallbackPath = "/signin-amazon";
  options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-amazon";
  options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/signout-amazon";
  options.Scope.Clear();
  options.Scope.Add("profile");
  options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

  var rsa = RSA.Create();
  var key = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa){KeyId = "1"};

  var jwtClaims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.IssuedAt, "now"),
                        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.JwtId, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                    };

  var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    "issuer",
                    "audience",
                    jwtClaims,
                    DateTime.UtcNow,
                    DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                    new SigningCredentials(key, "RS256"));

  var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
  handler.OutboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
  var token = handler.WriteToken(jwt);

  options.Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration
  {
      AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa",
      TokenEndpoint = "https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token",
      UserInfoEndpoint = "https://api.amazon.com/user/profile"
  };

  options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
  {
      ValidateTokenReplay = false,
      ValidateIssuer = false,
      ValidateAudience = false,
      ValidateLifetime = false,
      IssuerSigningKey = key
  };

  AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext hook = null;
  options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
  {
       OnAuthenticationFailed = async context =>
       {
           //context.SkipHandler();
       },
       OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context => { hook = context; },
       OnTokenResponseReceived = async context =>
       {
           context.TokenEndpointResponse.IdToken = token;
           hook.TokenEndpointResponse = context.TokenEndpointResponse;
       },
       OnUserInformationReceived = async context =>
       {
           var user = context.User;
           var claims = new[]
           {
               new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, user["user_id"].ToString()),
               new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, user["email"].ToString()),
               new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, user["name"].ToString())
           };
           context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
           context.Success();
       }
  };
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, neither Login with Amazon nor Evernote supports Open ID Connect. Other mentioned services do, which can be verified by visiting appropriate configuration site of each of them: [Google](https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration), [Microsoft](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration).

There are ofc others that are not preconfigured in .Net and can be used with it:
[Salesforce](https://login.salesforce.com/.well-known/openid-configuration)

As you probably noticed usually the configuration for Open ID Connect is stored on a site with "/.well-known/openid-configuration" suffix. This is called OpenID Connect metadata document and it contains most of the information required for an app to do sign-in. This includes information such as the URLs to use and the location of the service's public signing keys.

And now lets go for .Net configuration for custom Open ID Connect provider (I will use Salesforce as it supports Open ID):

```
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddFacebook(options =>
{
    options.AppId = Configuration["auth:facebook:appid"];
    options.AppSecret = Configuration["auth:facebook:appsecret"];
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("OpenIdConnectSalesforce", "Salesforce", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://login.salesforce.com";
    options.ClientId = Configuration["auth:salesforce:appid"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["auth:salesforce:appsecret"];
    options.ResponseType = "code";
});
```

And after launching web app we can see additional button to log in using Salesforce:
[image]

As for Evernote and Amazon you could use their SDKs and APIs to implement their log in methods respectively. I do believe that they support OAuth.

Answer (score 1):

Extended the solution by @d-f to use OAuth handler.

```cs
.AddOAuth("lwa-oauth", "OauthLoginWithAmazon", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

    options.ClientId = "amzn1.application-oa2-client.zzzzzzzzzzzz";
    options.ClientSecret = "4c0630b4166c901519a730835ezzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-amazon";
    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("profile");

    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa";
    options.TokenEndpoint = "https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token";
    options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.amazon.com/user/profile";

    options.Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
         OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
         {
            var accessToken = context.AccessToken;
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = 
                 await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(
                        new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, options.UserInformationEndpoint)
            {
              Headers = 
              {
                    Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken)
              }
            });
            responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string userInfoResponse = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var user = JObject.Parse(userInfoResponse);
            var claims = new[]
            {
              new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, user["user_id"].ToString()),
              new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, user["email"].ToString()),
              new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, user["name"].ToString())
            };
            context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
            context.Success();
       }
   };
})
```